# Is there a way to know the methods of an instance of an unknown class in Perl

Tags: perl, object

I have a program in Perl that uses a package that I got from another source. One of the functions of the method returns an object of an unknown class, Is there a way for me to get all the possible methods of an object without looking at its class implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really.

**TL;DR:**

- You can find the names of subroutines explicitly declared or placed into the object's class's namespace.
- **You can NOT distinguish which of these subroutines are object methods on your object, and which are class or non-object subs** (this is the most serious problem/limintation among those listed).
- You can NOT find the methods inherited by an object in the subclass from the superclass using this method, **unless** they were already called on your object.

  This can be coded around, by either inspecting `@ISA` of the class to [build up inheritance trees, or using on of proper CPAN modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870581/what-is-the-best-practice-for-finding-out-all-superclasses-of-a-perl-class).
- You can NOT find the methods that are dynamically added to the class (AUTOLOAD, manual method injection in the code somewhere).

**In detail**

1. You can find all of the subroutines in that class (by combining the fact that the class namespace is a hash so all identifiers in it are keys in that hash; and the `UNIVERSAL::can` call to separate subroutines).

   Therefore, if you are GUARANTEED (by non-technical contract) that 100% of subroutines in the class are object methods, AND that your class is NOT a subclass, you can find their list.

   ```
   package MyClass;
   use vars qw($z5);
   my $x = 11; our $y = 12; $z5 = 14; %z2 = (1=>2); # my, our, globals, hash
   sub new { return bless({}, $_[0]) }; # Constructor
   sub x1 { my $self = shift; print $_[0]; };
   sub y2  { my $self = shift; print $_[0]; };
   ##############################################################################
   package MySubClass;
   use vars qw(@ISA);
   @ISA = ("MyClass");
   sub z3 { return "" };
   ##############################################################################
   package main;
   use strict; use warnings;

   my $obj = MyClass->new();
   list_object_methods($obj);
   my $obj2 = MySubClass->new();
   list_object_methods($obj2);
   $obj2->x1();
   list_object_methods($obj2); # Add "x1" to the list!

   sub list_object_methods {
       my $obj = shift;
       my $class_name = ref($obj);
       no strict;
       my @identifiers = keys %{"${class_name}::"};
       use strict;
       my @subroutines = grep { UNIVERSAL::can($obj, $_) } @identifiers;
       print "Class: ${class_name}\n";
       print "Subroutines: \n=========\n"
           . join("\n", sort @subroutines) . "\n=========\n";
   }
   ```

   ... prints:

   ```
   Class: MyClass
   Subroutines:
   =========
   new
   x1
   y2
   =========
   Class: MySubClass
   Subroutines:
   =========
   new
   z3
   =========
   Class: MySubClass
   Subroutines:
   =========
   new
   x1
   z3
   =========
   ```

   Please note that the first-time list (for MySubClass) printed `new` and `z3` but NOT `x1` or `y2` - because `new` was executed and `z3` was declared in the class; but `x1` and `y2` was neither - they were merely theoretically inherited. BUT, once we executed an inherited `x1` method, then the second-time list included it, while still missing inherited `y2`.

   ---
2. But you can NOT, unfortunately, distinguish a subroutine that is an object method (e.g. treats the first argument it gets as an object), a class method (e.g. treats the first argument it gets as a class name) or a non-OO sub (treats first argument as regular argument).

   To distinguish between the 3, the ONLY way is to actually semantically analyze the code. Otherwise, you can't tell the difference between:

   ```
   sub s_print_obj {
       my ($self, $arg1) = @_;
       $s->{arg1} = $arg1;
       print "$arg1\n";
   }
   # $obj->s_print_obj("XYZ") prints "XYZ" and stores the data in the object

   sub s_print_class {
       my ($class, $arg1) = @_; 
       print "Class: $class\n";
       print "$arg1\n";
   }
   # $obj->s_print_class("XYZ") prints "Class: MyClass\nXYZ\n"

   sub s_print_static {
       my ($self, $arg1) = @_;
       print "$arg1\n";
   }
   # $obj->s_print_static("XYZ") prints stringified representation of $obj
   ```

   NOTE: As a matter of fact, some people actually write their class's methods - those that CAN work this way - to explicitly work in ALL 3 (or first 2) cases, no matter how the method is called.

Comment: *"You can NOT find the methods inherited by an object in the subclass from the superclass, unless they were already called on your object"*.  If I'm reading you correctly, you're saying `$obj->inherited_method` has to be run before you can spot `inherited_method`?  I don't think that's true or [these perl5i tests](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHWERN/perl5i-v2.9.1/t/Meta/methods.t) wouldn't work.  Got code to back that up?

Comment: @Schwern - see the second sentence in that bullet: "This can be coded around, by either inspecting ISA of the class to build up inheritance trees, or using on of proper CPAN modules.". "Can NOT" part was referring to the above-summarized technique of directly reading the namespace hash. The back up code to this (less grandiouse than you read it) statement is my code in the answer.

Comment: Oh. I just took walking `@ISA` as a given.

Answer (score 0):

DVK's answer is accurate, but a bit lengthy.  The short answer is yes you can, but you won't know what was intended as a public object method and what wasn't.  Private methods and functions imported from other modules may show up.

Simplest way to get the list of callable, concrete (ie. non-AUTOLOAD) methods is to use the [perl5i meta object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5i%3a%3aMeta)'s [methods()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5i%3a%3aMeta#methods) method.

```
use perl5i::2;

my $object = Something::Something->new;
my @methods = $object->mo->methods;
```

That at least eliminates a lot of code.

Comment: How does `methods` distinguish between object's methods and class's non-object subs (see my 3 examples in part #2)? POD didn't seem to have any clarification on that.

Comment: @DVK Simple: it doesn't. As you correctly pointed out, it can't. It just lists the available, concrete, callable methods doing all the inheritance walking and symbol table examination so you don't have to. I will correct a few pronouns in my answer to make this clearer. It *could* take advantage of perl5i's func/method distinction, but it currently doesn't.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit "a list of... methods" to "a list of subroutines (methods or not)"? ["Method" has a very specific connotation/meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29) in languages with OO features, [including Perl](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/01/adding-a-method-keyword-to-perl-5.html)

Comment: @DVK [I'd rather you put the energy into improving it](https://github.com/schwern/perl5i/issues/222). :)