# What is the best practice for finding all the superclasses of a Perl class?

Tags: perl, oop, superclass

Is there a standard CPAN way of finding out all the superclasses of a Perl class (or better yet entire superclass tree, up to UNIVERSAL)?

Or is the best practice to simply examine `@{"${$class}::ISA"}` for each class, class's parents etc?

Comment: Is this perhaps a trick question whose answer is you don’t want to do that? Sometimes you should just let polymorphism do its thing. Usually even, perhaps.

Comment: @tchrist - no trick. I never had to do that (as noted by your comment and the answers, it's not something one should usually do); so that when the need to consider "how" arose when answering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869511/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-methods-of-an-instance-of-an-unknown-class-in-perl/10869712#10869712), I was faced with the need to pick AN implementation. And I'm a firm believer in TIMTOWTDIBSWABTO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "standard way" because this is not a standard thing you want to do.  For anything other than visualization it is an OO red flag to want to inspect your inheritance tree.

In addition to Class::ISA, there is [mro::get_linear_isa()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?mro#mro::get_linear_isa%28$classname%5B,_$type%5D%29).  Both have been in core for a while so they could be considered "standard" for some definition.  Both of those show inheritance as a flat list, not a tree, which is useful mostly for deep magic.

The [perl5i meta object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5i::Meta) provides both [linear_isa()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5i::Meta#linear_isa), like mro (it just calls mro), and [ISA()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5i::Meta#ISA) which returns the class' `@ISA`.  It can be used to construct a tree using simple recursion without getting into symbol tables.

```
use perl5i::2;

func print_isa_tree($class, $depth) {
    $depth ||= 0;

    my $indent = "    " x $depth;
    say $indent, $class;

    for my $super_class ($class->mc->ISA) {
        print_isa_tree($super_class, $depth+1);
    }

    return;
}


my $Class = shift;
$Class->require;

print_isa_tree($Class);

__END__
DBIx::Class
    DBIx::Class::Componentised
        Class::C3::Componentised
    DBIx::Class::AccessorGroup
        Class::Accessor::Grouped
```

Comment: "For a while" - could you quantify that please? 5.12+? 5.8+?

Comment: Never mind. Too Lazy For Google. "Class::ISA was introduced to the Perl Core in release 5.8.0" (from ["Hidden Treasures of Perl Core" @perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/05/29/treasures.html));

Answer (score 5):

I think [Class::ISA](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aISA) is something like you are looking for

```
use Class::ISA;
use Mojolicious;
print join "\n", Class::ISA::super_path("Mojolicious");
```

Prints:

```
Mojo
Mojo::Base
```

However, it's not some kind of "best practice" since the whole task isn't something Perl programmers do every day.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely these days you want to use one of the functions from `mro`, such as [`mro::get_linear_isa`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/ext/mro/mro.pm#mro%3a%3aget_linear_isa%28%24classname%5b,_%24type%5d%29).

```
use mro;
my @superclasses = mro::get_linear_isa($class);
```

Comment: return type of `mro::get_linear_isa` is not array but arrayref !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is something like a "standard CPAN way". Examining `@ISA` is common practice - and also plausible, since techniques like `use base qw(...)` and `use parent -norequire, ...` also operate on top of `@ISA`...

Comment: "standard" as in "Use Text::CSV{_XS}?" is standard for CSV parsing. Yes, there's a gazillion modules for CSV parsing but this or 1-2 other ones are most mature, used by vast majority of developers etc...

Comment: OK, point taken. Well, either way, I'd consider examining `@ISA` as the "standard" then.