# Getting the root of a multi-level inheritance

Tags: perl, inheritance

I have the following inheritance in my Perl modules

```
'Class::Accessor'
       |
'Class::Accessor::Fast'
       |
'MYAPP::MOD::Conf'
       |
'MYAPP::MOD'
       |
'MYAPP::MOD::Test'
       |
'MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestChild'
       |
'MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild'
```

I want some way to get the immediate child of `MYAPP::MOD` given `MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild`. Is it possible to do without hardcoding depth?

In terms of code:

```
package MYAPP::MOD::Conf;
use base qw/Class::Accessor::Fast/;

package MYAPP::MOD;
use base qw(MYAPP::MOD::Configurable);

package MYAPP::MOD::Test;
use base qw(MYAPP::MOD);

package MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestChild;
use base qw(MYAPP::MOD::Test);

package MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild;
use base qw(MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestChild);
```

Comment: This is an *inheritance* chain, so there are no "children" as such. The base classes of `MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild` objects are listed in `@MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild::ISA`. If you explain what it is that you're trying to do then we may be able to help better

Comment: @Borodin thanks for the edit. My use case is I have to write a function which will return the immediate child of MYAPP::MOD given MYAPP::MOD::Test::TestGrandChild;

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really help. It's pretty much what you said in the question. I think you're using the wrong terminology, but I can't fathom what the *right* terminology is. Please can you give an example and explain your application?

Comment: In simple term If I am given package name "A" I need to know if it is using "use base" statement, if yes then package it is using in use base, I need to know if it is doing the same thing and so on until I reach MYAPP::MOD package name, If I reach MYAPP::MOD package name I need to return package from where I reached MYAPP::MOD.

Answer (score 0):

There is [mro::get_linear_isa](https://metacpan.org/pod/mro#mro::get_linear_isa-classname-type) that you can use to get a linear inheritance chain. It will not work if you have multiple inheritance in a class.

```
package AA;
use Moose;

package BB;
use Moose;
extends 'AA';

package CC;
use Moose;
extends 'BB';

package DD;
use Moose;
extends 'CC';

package main;
use Data::Printer;
use mro;

my @foo = mro::get_linear_isa("DD");
p @foo;

__END__
[
    [0] [
        [0] "DD",
        [1] "CC",
        [2] "BB",
        [3] "AA",
        [4] "Moose::Object"
    ]
]
```

Also see [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872275/1331451) to [What is the best practice for finding out all superclasses of a Perl class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870581/what-is-the-best-practice-for-finding-out-all-superclasses-of-a-perl-class).